# Doble envió de formulario por ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estoy tratando de realizar el sistema de autentificación y registro de mi aplicación en codeigniter, para esto tengo un controlador llamado Auth, con dos vista index(login) y registro, ademas cuento con dos funciones login y register, del lado de la vista utilizo ajax para hacer la comunicación con esas dos funciones, estando en la vista de login al dar click en el boton de ingresar envia los datos al la funcion correspondiente, todo bien hasta el momento, **EL PROBLEMA** radica en que si el usuario ingresa mal las credenciales, la función retorna un json dando unas indicaciones de que el usuario y/o contraseña son incorrectos, al momento de enviar nuevamente los datos **POR ALGUNA RAZÓN** envia dos veces el mismo formulario.

Como pueden ver en esta imagen, hace lo que tiene que hacer enviar el formulario una sola vez y el servidor responde

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta otra imagen, al estar mal las credenciales el usuario trata de enviar nuevamente, pero envía dos veces el mismo formulario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta otra imagen esta el codigo ajax que se ejecuta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien podría ayudarme a dar solución a este pequeño error que se me esta presentando.

Comment: Debes llamar `ev.preventDefault();` antes de la llamada `$.ajax`

Comment: Amigo nada, sigue saliendo lo mismo, envia dos veces el mismo formulario